# Domain CNAME to different domain with path via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with products. Every product is available by url:

- http://example.com/product-one
- http://example.com/product-two
- etc

Eeach of these URLs has RewriteRule in htaccess like:

- `RewriteRule ^product-one$ index.php?product_id=1`
- `RewriteRule ^product-two$ index.php?product_id=2`
- etc

Also I have domains like

- product-one.com
- product-two.com

I want to make some kind of proxy with htaccess where product-one.com will be example.com/product-one.

I tried to use this solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^product-one.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/product-one [P]
```

And it shows me a page, but paths are broken and browser doesn't load CSS and JS from initial path. It was idea to use iframe, but I already using in in example.com/product-one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^product-one.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/product-one [P]
```

string 2 - all existing folders will not be processed

string 3 -all existing files will not be processed

Comment: With string 2 pathes are ignored.
With string 3 pathes are ok. But I get this JS error:
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://product-one.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: example.com/product-one contains iframe with html

Comment: This fired when you try to call ajax to another domain, please check this article for more info about Same origin policy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin
For fix try to add this code `document.domain = 'yourdomain.com'`